# WebElement is an interface - how can methods be called on it successfully?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Since WebElement is an interface, it means that all the methods present in the WebElement interface are abstract, i.e. they don't have a body. Also, we know that we cannot access the methods of the interface directly using reference to the interface (because the methods don't have any implementation)

Now, consider the following code:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(//xpath of a button);
button.click();
```

Can someone explain how is it possible here to access the click() method of the interface WebElement through 'button' which is nothing but a reference to the interface WebElement?

Answer (score 1):

The `WebElement` interface is implemented by `AndroidWebElement`, `HtmlUnitWebElement`, or `RemoteWebElement`.

The `click` method is actually executed on one of these concrete classes (which is returned by `findElement`).

See the following documentation for further details:

- [Interface WebDriver findElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [Interface WebElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)
- [Class AndroidWebElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/android/library/AndroidWebElement.html)
- [Class HtmlUnitWebElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitWebElement.html)
- [Class RemoteWebElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html)

Answer (score 1):

SearchContext and Takescreenshot interfaces are parent of WebElement interface.
Now RemoteWebElement, htmlunitWebElement classes implements WebElement interface.
Here I am attaching a screen shot for your better understanding.[image]

You can see the same thing by installing decompiler in your IDE and right click on WebElement interface. You'd see the same reflection :